# October CMS: share partial between themes

Tags: laravel, octobercms

What is the simple way to share partials between themes. Assets are possible but i am having issue with whole partials. I have a multi-theme site managed/activated by sub-domain policies/logic.

SOLUTIONS
    /**
     *
     * Renders a requested partial in context of this component,
     * see Cms\Classes\Controller@renderPartial for usage.
     */

```
/**
 * @param $themeName
 * @param $partialName
 * @param $data
 * @return mixed
 * @throws \Cms\Classes\CmsException
 */
public function renderThemePartial($partialName, $themeName, $data)
{
    $theme = Theme::getActiveTheme();
    if($themeName) {
        $theme = Theme::load($themeName);
    }

    $controller = new Controller($theme);

    return $controller->renderPartial($partialName, $data);
}

/**
 *
 * Renders a requested content in context of this component,
 * see Cms\Classes\Controller@renderContent for usage.
 */

/**
 * @param $themeName
 * @param $contentName
 * @param $data
 * @return string
 * @throws \Cms\Classes\CmsException
 */
public function renderThemeContent($contentName, $themeName, $data)
{
    $theme = Theme::getActiveTheme();
    if($themeName) {
        $theme = Theme::load($themeName);
    }

    $controller = new Controller($theme);

    return $controller->renderContent($contentName, $data);
}


public function registerMarkupTags()
{
    return [
        'functions' => [
            'partial_from_theme' => [$this, 'themePartial'],
            'content_from_theme' => [$this, 'themeContent'],
        ],
        'filters' => [
            'theme_asset'   => [$this, 'themeUrl']
        ]
    ];
}

/**
 * @param $requested
 * @return string
 */
public function themeUrl($requested)
{
    $asset = $requested[0];
    $theme = $requested[1];
    $theme = Theme::load($theme);
    $themeDir = $theme->getDirName();
    if (is_array($asset)) {
        $_url = Url::to(CombineAssets::combine($asset, themes_path().'/'.$themeDir));
    }
    else {
        $_url = Config::get('cms.themesPath', '/themes').'/'.$themeDir;
        if ($asset !== null) {
            $_url .= '/'.$asset;
        }
        $_url = Url::asset($_url);
    }
    return $_url;
}

/**
 * @param $partialName
 * @param null $themeName
 * @param array $parameters
 * @return mixed
 * @throws \Cms\Classes\CmsException
 */
public function themePartial($partialName, $themeName = null, $parameters = [])
{
    return $this->renderThemePartial($partialName, $themeName, $parameters);
}

/**
 * @param $contentName
 * @param null $themeName
 * @param array $parameters
 * @return string
 * @throws \Cms\Classes\CmsException
 */
public function themeContent($contentName, $themeName = null, $parameters = [])
{
    return $this->renderThemeContent($contentName, $themeName, $parameters);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can use `Plugin component` here you can `add component to page` and `use its partial`.

You need to define partial `[ you can add as many as you like ]` in component.

[image]

And just use that `partial` like below in page , now `this same thing you can do in other themes as well.`

[image]

When you `change partial` it will `affect in all other themes` like its `shared across multiple themes.`

> `Down side` will be that you `can not change its content from backend`, you need to manually change that file from ftp or other manner.

---

### Partial from another theme

Hmm

you can add custom twig function for that may be

> In any of your plugin you can add this code

```
public function registerMarkupTags()
{
    return [
        'functions' => [                
            'theme_partial' => [$this, 'themePartial'],
        ]
    ];
}

public function themePartial($partialName, $themeName = null, $vars = [])
{
    $theme = Theme::getActiveTheme();
    if($themeName) {
      $theme = Theme::load($themeName);
    }
    $template = call_user_func([Partial::class, 'load'], $theme, $partialName);
    $partialContent = $template->getTwigContent();
    $html = Twig::parse($partialContent, $vars);
    return $html;
}
```

Now inside your theme when you want to use partial you can use

```
{{ theme_partial('call_from_other_theme', 'stemalo' ,{'name':'hardik'}) }}
                                           ^ Your theme name here.
```

> `themes/stemalo/partials/call_from_other_theme.htm` content

```
description = "Shared Partial."

[viewBag]
==
<div id="shared_partial">
    <h1>Another Theme Partial : {{name}}</h1>
</div>
```

this way you can use partial from another themes.

> `you aksed for access to theme directory` here may be you can just you need to pass theme name, and `its dynamic you can pass variable as theme name so it can pick any thing you like.

If any doubt please comment.

Comment: Hey Hardik, I appreciate the input. I am aware of that being a solution, and i have considered it. Again that would mean modification the original theme to now support the new component, doubling the work required. I was hoping for something akin allowing the twig {% partial %} directive access to <theme> directory.

Comment: updated answer `Partial from another theme` can you check it if it may helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using custom Twig Functions